# Easiest way to parse a single, large text file across multiple client machines?

Tags: perl, parsing, distributed, logging

I've been given the task of writing a webapp that analyzes text files given a single regular expression. The text files I am given range anywhere from 500MB to 3GB. I am currently using Perl as my parsing engine. I've been reading about mapReduce and Hadoop but it seems like the set up is only worth it given very,very large amounts of data, much larger than the amounts I am parsing.

What would be a good way to go about this? Right now a 500MB file takes anywhere from 4 to 6 minutes to parse, which isn't too bad, but the 3GB files take forever, and the webserver usually times out before it can get output from the Perl script and generate a report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's partition your file into 100 chunks, and use `seek` to let an arbitrary process work on an arbitrary part of the file.

```
my $chunk = $ARGV[0];      # a user input, from 0 to 99
my $size = -s $THE_FILE;
my $startByte = int($chunk * $size / 100);
my $endByte = int(($chunk + 1) * $size) / 100);

open my $fh, '<', $THE_FILE;
seek $fh, 0, $startByte;
scalar <$fh>;      # skip current line in case we have seek'd to the middle of a line

while (<$fh>) {
    # ... process this section of the file ...
    last if tell($fh) >= $endByte;
}
```

Now run this program 100 times on whatever machines you have available, passing the arguments 0 to 99 once to each program.

Answer (score 2):

Actually hadoop is surprisingly easy to install and use (especially if you don't have huge data and don't need to optimize it). I had a similar task a while (processing logs in the range of about 5GB) and it took me no more than a couple of hours to install it on 5 machines, just using the tutorial and doc on their site. Then the programming is really easy, just read from STDIN and write to STDOUT!
Probably making your own split and distribute script (even if you make it on top of something like Gearman) will take more than installing hadoop.